# Confused about setting variables, stop loss recalculates every bar, trying to make it on entry only

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Fairly new to pinescript, but have done some indicators before. My problem is now I'm trying to automate a strategy. Extending a keltner channel into a reversion into a strategy.

I enter when price closes below, and plan to exit when it reaches the basis/center line. Instead of a limit/profit, I found adding a small trail price at basis gives better profit factors. But the difficulty I have is the stop loss. I made a seperate line 2/3 the distance of the basis, to act as a 1.5 to 1 RR. But the stop loss line recalculates every bar. I read using var can make it static, but how do i do this? I added var to the StopLong and in the strategy entry stop section, using var StopLong or :=, but each time the code breaks.

Example below (long):

```
StopLong = close - ((Basis - close) * 0.66) 

// Strategy conditions 
if close < LowerBand 
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, stop = StopLong) 

strategy.exit("Exit Long", "Long", trail_price = basis, trail_offset = 3)
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously the `close` price keeps changing and causing your stop loss price to be updated.

You need to use the `var` keyword and only update your stop loss price once.

```
is_new_long = (strategy.position_size > 0) and (strategy.position_size > strategy.position_size[1])

var float StopLong = na

if (is_new_long)
    StopLong := close - ((Basis - close) * 0.66)
```

Then you need to reset `StopLong` whenever you exit a trade.